# Generating a random consonant in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, character

I'm trying to randomly generate a consonant but I'm running into trouble.

I created an array with all the consonants and am able to generate a random number.
What I'm trying to do now is associate that random number with its matching index number from the array to print out the character.

See my code below I hope that makes sense! Thanks!

```
function genCon(){

var con = ["b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z"];

var randomCon = Math.floor((Math.random()*con.length)+1);

console.log(randomCon);

}
```

Comment: So `con[randomCon]`?

Comment: Oh my god thank you Kerndog! So simple! As you can see I'm quite new to Javascript lol!

Comment: A random constant? Hmmm… might be an oxymoron. ;-)

Comment: just a heads up, you'll want to get rid the `+1` as this will give you an index outside of your array, and you'll never get `b` as your result (index 0)

Comment: Thanks Nick! You actually came to my rescue! Thought I was using Math.floor incorrectly! You genius!